# How can I make a mindmap visualisation in a website?

Tags: javascript, css

A client of mine asked me if he can show the areas he works in as a 'mindmap' on his website. What is the best way to approach this? How can I make it so it's responsive as well?

See attachment for drawing of the mindmap.

Thanks in advance!

Ferre

[image: Click here for screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use  website prototyping tools. I prefer [Webflow](https://webflow.com/). This [blog](http://blog.lemonstand.com/9-best-prototyping-tools-2017/) will help